# How to bind a checkedlistbox to a combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, checkedlistbox

I have a combobox that user can select an Item and based on that item in the checkedlistbox some other items need to be populated.

1. I can bind the combobox to a column in my database when all the values in the column are different. However, in this case in that column there are duplicated items and I do not want to have multiple items of the same type. I just want to have one "Crawler" and one "All Terrain" in the combobox.

This is the code that used to use to bind source to a combobox, but does not work for this case.

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "crane index";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "crane type";
comboBox1.DataSource = test.Tables["cranemaintable"];
```

this the table in the database

```
| Crane Index | Crane Model Number |  Crane Type |
|:-----------:|:------------------:|:-----------:|
| 221         | LR 1400-1          | Crawler     |
| 258         | CC 2800            | Crawler     |
| 262         | CC 2400-1          | All Terrain |
| 265         | CC 6800            | Crawler     |
| 277         | LR 11350           | All Terrain |
```

1. Database: MS Access
2. Dataset: test
3. Name of the table: cranemaintable

I have checked the other questions related to mine but could not find an answer to my problem.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Update:
This is what I have found and worked for me.

```
// create a list that holds all the crane types but it should not have duplicated items
        List<string> crane_type = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i< test.Tables["cranemaintable"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!crane_type.Contains(test.Tables["cranemaintable"].Rows[i]["crane type"]))
            {
                crane_type.Add(Convert.ToString(test.Tables["cranemaintable"].Rows[i]["crane type"]));
            }                
        }        
        //bind the crane_type list to the combobox1
        comboBox1.DataSource = crane_type;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please only ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: 1. try SELECT DISTINCT sql for combobox RowSource or create a lookup table for use as combobox RowSource; 2. research cascading combobox/listbox

Comment: Thank you, as the questions were related I asked both of them.

Comment: Still 2 separate issues. Each has a solution that is independent of the other.

Comment: I have removed the second question.

Comment: @Ramtin let me see if I understand you properly, you want a `combobox` that will read that table and give you two options to pick from (`crawler` and `all terrain`) and then a `checkedlistbox` that you can pick from `CC 2400-1` and `LR 11350` if you have picked all terrain ?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I want. However, I had to removed the second part of the question. But that is the final goal for me. If you can help me with both of them, it would be a big improve for me. @ Mohammed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first my answer is ugly but it works and its the only one I know, so we start with you importing your databasetabe into a list
this is a class you can use

```
public class myclass
   {
      public string CraneIndex { get; set; }
      public string CraneModelNumber { get; set; }
      public string CraneType { get; set; }
   }
```

and then make 3 lists

```
  List<myclass> myclasses = new List<myclass>();
  List<myclass> myclasses1 = new List<myclass>();
  List<myclass> myclasses2 = new List<myclass>();
```

here you import your table into the list `myclasses` and then we filter the main list that came from the database to only have unique types

```
      myclasses1 = myclasses.GroupBy(myclass => myclass.CraneType).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
      comboBox1.DataSource = myclasses1;
      comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CraneType";
```

go to the `combobox` and subscribe to the `selectedindexchanged` property and add this into its function

```
 myclasses2.Clear();
    foreach (var item in myclasses)
    {
       if (comboBox1.Text==item.CraneType)
       {
         myclasses2.Add(item);
       }
    }
    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in myclasses2)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.CraneModelNumber);
    }
    this.checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "cranemodels";
    checkedListBox1.Refresh();
```

Let me know if you need any more help or explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have used your idea but implemented it in another way. I am not sure if my way is completely correct or efficient. However, it is working. I will update my question with the method that I have used.Let me know what you think. Also I have another question related to this problem, I would be glad if you can help me if you have time, please.

Comment: yea sure I will gladly look at your other question but where are you posting it ?

Comment: Is there any way that I can send it to you directly? like an email address? if no I will post it on SO as a new question.

Comment: @ramtin post it as a question and I will check your new question in a couple of mins

Comment: Unfortunately SO does not let me to post another question as I have asked 2 questions so far. Anyway, thanks for you help.

Comment: @Ramtin I am sorry, when you do tag me and I will have a look on it. Best of luck